# Understanding Spark correlation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, cross-correlation, pearson-correlation

I was reading Spark correlation algorithm source code and while going through the code, I coulddn't understand this particular peace of code.

This is from the file : org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/BLAS.scala

```
 def spr(alpha: Double, v: Vector, U: Array[Double]): Unit = {
    val n = v.size
    v match {
      case DenseVector(values) =>
        NativeBLAS.dspr("U", n, alpha, values, 1, U)
      case SparseVector(size, indices, values) =>
        val nnz = indices.length
        var colStartIdx = 0
        var prevCol = 0
        var col = 0
        var j = 0
        var i = 0
        var av = 0.0
        while (j < nnz) {
          col = indices(j)
          // Skip empty columns.
          colStartIdx += (col - prevCol) * (col + prevCol + 1) / 2
          av = alpha * values(j)
          i = 0
          while (i <= j) {
            U(colStartIdx + indices(i)) += av * values(i)
            i += 1
          }
          j += 1
          prevCol = col
        }
    }
  }
```

I do not know Scala and that could be the reason I could not understand it. Can someone explain what is happening here.

It is being called from Rowmatrix.scala

```
  def computeGramianMatrix(): Matrix = {
    val n = numCols().toInt
    checkNumColumns(n)
    // Computes n*(n+1)/2, avoiding overflow in the multiplication.
    // This succeeds when n <= 65535, which is checked above
    val nt = if (n % 2 == 0) ((n / 2) * (n + 1)) else (n * ((n + 1) / 2))

    // Compute the upper triangular part of the gram matrix.
    val GU = rows.treeAggregate(new BDV[Double](nt))(
      seqOp = (U, v) => {
        BLAS.spr(1.0, v, U.data)
        U
      }, combOp = (U1, U2) => U1 += U2)

    RowMatrix.triuToFull(n, GU.data)
  }
```

The correlation is defined here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient

The final goal is to understand the Spark correlation algorithm.

**Update 1**: Relevent paper https://stanford.edu/~rezab/papers/linalg.pdf

Comment: read the comment : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/25b4f41d239ac67402566c0254a893e2e58ae7d8/mllib-local/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/BLAS.scala#L265 as for the rest, I think I have longly explained it in the chat room(s)

Comment: Yes and a great thanks for the explanation but I wanted to know about this spr Algorithm, any references for it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not answering any more of your questions.

Comment: Ok. If i said anything wrong, pardon me. Anyways thanks for explaining the correlation thing. I am meeting my professor on Wednesday.

Comment: No need to be sorry. It's just that your questions are very broad and I felt like wasting my time with long exchanges. Explaining this amount of code isn't something you can get on this site to be honest.

Comment: Needless to remind that this seems like a homework assignment where you need to find your answers and not just other handling them for you. I'm as harsh as I much I'm willing to help. Sorry